# How to alert value inside object

Tags: javascript

I have an object from which I want to alert the value **"tr_name"**

My object containing this value is here:

```
[{"cells":[{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":290,"y":450},"size":{"width":90,"height":54},"angle":0,"id":"0c53af29-a635-4e74-8759-6d31472e0ffb","embeds":"","z":1,"wi_name":"","wi_displayName":"","wi_description":"","wi_join":"<None>","wi_split":"<None>","wi_performingUser":"","wi_workitem_variables":"","wi_expected_activity_time":null,"wi_expected_user_time":null,"wi_maximum_activity_time":null,"wi_initial_delay":null,"wi_time_unit":"Seconds","wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,"wi_custom_page":"","attrs":{"rect":{"fill":"#0000ff","width":50,"height":30,"rx":2,"ry":2,"stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},"text":{"fill":"#ffffff","text":"Activity","font-size":10,"font-family":"Arial","stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":0,"font-weight":400}}},{"type":"link","source":{"id":"0c53af29-a635-4e74-8759-6d31472e0ffb"},"target":{"x":720,"y":480},"id":"7086cf67-2254-4113-a9ca-564d4dd8c0f9","embeds":"","z":2,"smooth":false,"manhattan":false,"labels":[],"attrs":{".marker-source":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(1)","fill":"#000000"},".marker-target":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(1)","fill":"#000000"},".connection":{"stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},".attributes":{"tr_name":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","tr_description":"","tr_rules":"Rule 1","tr_value":"true","tr_rule_source":"BPM"}}}]},"{}","{}","{}","{}","{}"]
```

So far I try my alert like this with no result:

```
var selectedObjectDataText = JSON.stringify(this.selection.invoke('toJSON'));
var selectedObjectDataJSON = JSON.parse(selectedObjectDataText);
alert(selectedObjectDataJSON[0].[".attributes"]["tr_name"]);
```

How should I take it please?

Comment: post your full json

Comment: The excerpt you posted is invalid.

Comment: alert(selectedObjectDataJSON[0][".attributes"]["tr_name"]); should work

Comment: What you have shown appears to be not a string, but a JavaScript object. Is it really a string? In any case, why on earth would you stringify something only to immediately turn around and parse it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to your data was incomplete.

**Explanations**

*JSON METHODS*

- `JSON.parse` convert a string (JSON formated) into an **JSON Object**
- `JSON.stringify` convert an  **JSON Object** into a String

*ALERT JSON*

- For a **single JSON value** you just need to write the complete JSON data path (no `JSON.stringify` needed)
  `alert(selectedObjectDataJSON[0].cells[1].attrs['.attributes'].tr_name);`
- For an **JSON Object**, you need to `JSON.stringify` it before `alert`
  `alert(JSON.stringify(selectedObjectDataJSON[0].cells[1].attrs['.attributes']);`

*LIVE DEMO*

- https://jsfiddle.net/Ldmrn0fu/

Comment: Thanks! Fully comprehensive!!

Comment: webenginious there is a code smell going on, could you check my answer as the problem has not been pointed out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've updated my answer to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a JavaScript object with you and you can get the value of tr_name as follows (I've formatted the JSON you provided using a JSON formatter).

You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, they do the following

`JSON.stringify` turns a JavaScript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

`JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into a JavaScript object.

```js
var json = [
   {
      "cells":[
         {
            "type":"basic.Rect",
            "position":{
               "x":290,
               "y":450
            },
            "size":{
               "width":90,
               "height":54
            },
            "angle":0,
            "id":"0c53af29-a635-4e74-8759-6d31472e0ffb",
            "embeds":"",
            "z":1,
            "wi_name":"",
            "wi_displayName":"",
            "wi_description":"",
            "wi_join":"<None>",
            "wi_split":"<None>",
            "wi_performingUser":"",
            "wi_workitem_variables":"",
            "wi_expected_activity_time":null,
            "wi_expected_user_time":null,
            "wi_maximum_activity_time":null,
            "wi_initial_delay":null,
            "wi_time_unit":"Seconds",
            "wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,
            "wi_custom_page":"",
            "attrs":{
               "rect":{
                  "fill":"#0000ff",
                  "width":50,
                  "height":30,
                  "rx":2,
                  "ry":2,
                  "stroke-width":1,
                  "stroke-dasharray":"0"
               },
               "text":{
                  "fill":"#ffffff",
                  "text":"Activity",
                  "font-size":10,
                  "font-family":"Arial",
                  "stroke":"#000000",
                  "stroke-width":0,
                  "font-weight":400
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"link",
            "source":{
               "id":"0c53af29-a635-4e74-8759-6d31472e0ffb"
            },
            "target":{
               "x":720,
               "y":480
            },
            "id":"7086cf67-2254-4113-a9ca-564d4dd8c0f9",
            "embeds":"",
            "z":2,
            "smooth":false,
            "manhattan":false,
            "labels":[

            ],
            "attrs":{
               ".marker-source":{
                  "d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z",
                  "transform":"scale(1)",
                  "fill":"#000000"
               },
               ".marker-target":{
                  "d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z",
                  "transform":"scale(1)",
                  "fill":"#000000"
               },
               ".connection":{
                  "stroke":"#000000",
                  "stroke-width":1,
                  "stroke-dasharray":"0"
               },
               ".attributes":{
                  "tr_name":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                  "tr_description":"",
                  "tr_rules":"Rule 1",
                  "tr_value":"true",
                  "tr_rule_source":"BPM"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "{}",
   "{}",
   "{}",
   "{}",
   "{}"
];

var result = json[0].cells[1]['attrs']['.attributes']['tr_name'];
console.log(result);
```